# diagonal image overlay via css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a div overlay, set at 5% opacity, which creates a diagonal bounding box around the first line of text in this image. It seems to me that if I have the x,y coordinates for the four corners I should be able to create the overlay but I cannot figure out what the proper syntax would be to mark out the div.  Am I wrong in thinking this can be done, and if not can someone point me at some methods for doing so?

[image: Image that I want to draw the overlay on]

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `canvas` and javascript for simple cases you can use instead the `transform` property of css divs. For example with

```
#diag {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.25);
    width: 700px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 160px;
    transform: rotate(2deg) skew(30deg)
}
```

you can get a div positioned on the first line of the text in the image that can be styled easily with CSS for borders and that can be used directly for events (hover, clicks).

If you need to specify 4 corners however just a single transform is not enough in general and you have to draw your overlay in a canvas placed over the image. This works because a canvas is by default transparent and only what you explicitly draw will be visible leaving the image untouched in other areas. For example using:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(166, 282);
ctx.lineTo(855, 296);
ctx.lineTo(897, 351);
ctx.lineTo(212, 349);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0";
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

I've highlighted the third row in green (fill command) also adding a border (stroke command).

[image: fiddle output]

http://jsfiddle.net/hr9afs4z/1/

Comment: This solves the problem as I asked it, but now that I'm thinking about it it doesn't solve my actual problem.  I'm going to vote for this answer and re-ask the question with all of my parameters.

Comment: @medievalmatt: morphing a div so that you can specify all 4 corners is not possible with HTML because the transformation is just a single matrix. For drawing a general polygon you need to use a `canvas`. I'll extend the answer for that.